# Findstr -- exclude a file type -- search only ascii

Tags: command-line-arguments, dos, findstr

I want to run a FINDSTR dos command in a way beyond what it is easily found in "findstr /?".  How would I run findstr so that it only searches ascii files.  (I am not sure if that is possible. My gut feeling is that it is not possible)  Additionally, how would I run this command line so that it would exclude some file times.  For example, what if I wanted to exclude .psd files

Answer (score 8):

What is wrong with the `/P` option that is described in the help?

```
/P         Skip files with non-printable characters.
```

It worked for me.

To take further control of which files are searched, simply iterate the files with a for loop and add whatever logic you need. To skip .psd files and also skip binary files:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /a-d /b^|findstr /live ".psd"') do findstr /p "search" "%%F"
```

Use a single percent instead of double percents if run from the command line.